# Why does IE 7 not render this site correctly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Look at my website:  www.mrdavisonline.com
It renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but IE 7 butchers it.  I am a high school math teacher with some programming experience, and this summer I decided to get full control of my webpage for my classes.  I found a fluid web template online and worked on my website.  I don't know a lot about css (other than what I taught myself).  What am I missing?  Many of my students are still using IE 7 which means they can't access my page.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Supporting versions of IE that are older than 8 can be quite a pain. What exactly does IE do to the page?  I'm running linux, so I can't see it.

Comment: Doesn't look so hot in IE8 either..

Comment: *"Many of my students are still using IE 7"* - Why? What kind of people are they? Tell them to switch to a modern browser. If you were working at a retirement home I would understand, but students... ?

Comment: @Trevor: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

Comment: Wrong <h*> code closures. </h3>, </h4> - is correct way. Currently your h3 is amplifying h4 so text size is huge.

Comment: Thanks to all!  I am learning this website thing.  I appreciate all comments, and this really helped me a lot.  I had no idea where to look.  Now, I have some good tools at my disposal.  And they are high school students.  I can't change all of the their technology setups.  Many of them just use their parent's computers, and if they have their own, they know Facebook and not much else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems here too:

```
<h3>Mr. Davis Online<h3/>
<h4>Healdsburg High School<h4/>
```

closing those tags should be

```
</h3> not <h3/>
```

You have

```
Body {font-size:62.5%}
```

which will be a problem for sure.  Don't use a percentage here - px, em are fine.

I also think the order of your H1 shorthand is off.  Should be:

```
font:font-style | font-variant | font-weight | font-size | line-height | font-family
```

Compare to yours:

```
H1 {bold 2em Tahoma, sans-serif}
```

Comment: `font-size:62.5%` is actual common practice to use to normalize enlarging text font-sizes on cross-browser basis, this way 1em = 10px. If you hardcode em's or px's font sizes will be inconsistent on enlarging.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Closing those h3 and h4 tags was it.  I have other things to look at for my site, but that is a start.

Comment: And I learned something from @arma!  Good to know.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be your start. Basically the pages are having invalid markup. Checking the site through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mrdavisonline.com%2FTrigResources.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you have many errors scattered throughout your pages. Please get [a web editor](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) which can give you some real time validation and start working through your errors. Once you do that I'm sure that you'll be much closer to having your site render in IE7 the way you think it should.

Good luck, and I hope this helps you some.

Comment: This will help me quite a bit.  I have been doing all of my writing of HTML in Notepad++, not a real web editor.  Thanks!